# parse datetime string to datetime object without setting a format

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a `datetime` string in the following format: `2021-02-25T04:39:55Z`.

Can I parse it to `datetime` object without explicitly telling Python how?

`strptime()` requires you to set the format.

Comment: another option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62769371/10197418 (Python 3.7+). btw. your format is pretty standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `parse` method from `dateutil.parser` module which converts a `str` object to a datetime object:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
dtstr = '2021-02-25T04:39:55Z'
dt = parse(dtstr)
print(dt)
```

Output:

```
2021-02-25 04:39:55+00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dateutil, since your date and time format looks pretty standard.

```
from dateutil import parser as dtparse

dtparse.parse('2021-02-25T04:39:55Z')
```

Which returns :

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 25, 4, 39, 55, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new function and call it strptime that calls datetime.strptime:

```
from datetime import datetime

def strptime(time_, time_fmt=None):
    time_fmt = time_fmt or r"Your Own Default Format Here"
    return datetime.strptime(time_, time_fmt)
```

Other than that I prefer if you utilize `dateutil` as recommended above.

Answer (score 1):

pandas can also be used

```py
import pandas as pd

datetime_str = "2021-02-25T04:39:55Z"
my_datetime = pd.to_datetime(datetime_str).to_pydatetime()
print(my_datetime)
print(type(my_datetime))
# output
# 2021-02-25 04:39:55+00:00
# <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Comment: pandas uses dateutil's parser internally to infer the format, afaik